# C # - Check for condition before accessing method

Tags: c#, methods, attributes, conditional-statements

What is the best implementation for checking for a condition before accessing a method ?

Rather than using an If statement inside top of each method or using exception handling in each method , from what i understand from attributes is that they could tag methods with specific actions before accessing them, i have seen this in asp.net and some java web frame works with something like authentication for example , that i can make annotations or attributes in top of my method to check whether this user is authorized or not before even accessing this method.

Now can i write my own custom attribute for checking internet connection for example before accessing a method ?

I'm not asking for some code , I just want confirmation that i'm on the right path.

Comment: You are probably not on the right path. It's hard to say without a more precise explanation of the question. But there are few attributes that the run-time automatically processes, and you won't in general be able to create one yourself, at least not without the assistance of some code-injection library to help. IMHO, you are better off just doing this kind of thing "the old-fashioned way", unless it's part of a much bigger need where it makes sense to use such a code-injection library.

Comment: The function attributes in MVC are handy for controller entry points. It adds a bit of extra security for a function that opens out to the world, which is why I think conditions are checked in that way. For internal logic flow the more classic logic branches would be more readable in my opinion

Comment: see this link this is an example to what want to do
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do without further clarification, but there is a popular way to check conditions before executing code that doesn't require use of attributes/large nested `if`s. It is called a guard clause. It's extremely popular in constructor injection, but there are many great use cases.

Here's an example of a method that uses a guard clause to verify that a valid `InternetConnection` was passed to the method:

```
public void DoSomethingWithInternetConnection(InternetConnection internetConnection)
{
    // Guard clause
    if(internetConnection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    // Execute code that requires a valid internet connection
    internetConnection.DoSomething();
}
```

You should be able to see how you could extend this to check other scenarios, or use it elsewhere.

Comment: ok , what i'm trying to do is that most of my application is calling web apis , and i don't want inside each method that calls this api to add exception handling or if statements to avoid my application from crashing if there were no internet connection, and i'm trying to do this with least code and in an efficient fashion

Comment: @user2469133: In that case, you can simply handle that exception at a higher level (the caller of the methods which refer to the Web API). Let the exception bubble up and handle it appropriately.